# If $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, then $ xyz \equiv 0\pmod{60} $ (Pythagorean triples)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

> Prove that, if $x$, $y$ and $z$ are integers, and if $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, then $ xyz \equiv 0\pmod{60} $.

**Attempt:**

$ xyz \equiv 0\pmod{60} \iff 60\mid xyz$. Now notice that $60 = 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 $ so the statement $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5|xyz $ is equivalent to the original statement.

Now I'd have to prove separately that $3|xyz$, $4|xyz$, and $5|xyz$, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

At the same time, it will likely be too much work to prove each of these statements separately, so any other more concise/direct way to tackle this problem is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: It's actually pretty simple if you consider squares modulo 3, 4, and 5. They will force you to conclude that 3 divides at least once of them, etc.

Comment: @CameronWilliams you mind elaborating?

Comment: Squares are $\equiv 0,1,4 \pmod 5$. If you don't use $0$ then none of the sum works: $1+1\equiv 2\pmod 5$, $4+4\equiv 3\pmod 5$ are impossible since $2,3$ are not squares. You cannot have $1+4$ since that gives $0\pmod 5$ on the RHS. So you must have a $0\pmod 5$ for one of the terms, which means $5$ divides one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to note:

If $m \equiv -1,0,1 \pmod 3$ then $m^2 \equiv 0,1\pmod 3$.  If none of them $x, y$ or $z$ are divisible by $3$ then $x^2,y^2,z^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $1+1\equiv 1\pmod 3$ is a contradiction.  So at least one of $x,y,z$ is divisible by $3$.

Similarly if $m\equiv -2,-1,0,1,2 \pmod 5$ then $m^2 \equiv \pm 1, 0\pmod 5$.  If none of $x,y,$or $z$ are divisible by $5$ then we have $\pm 1 +\pm 1 \equiv \pm 1$ which is impossible.  So at least one of $x,y,z$ is divisible by $5$.

$4$ is a problem in not being prime we have $m\equiv 2\implies m^2 \equiv 0$. And it implies it's not enough to assume none of them are divisible by $4$ but that at most one is divisible by $2$.

So if $m\equiv -1,0,1,2\pmod 4$ then $m^2 \equiv 0,1$ and at most one is divisible by $2$  we can have $(0,1)+(0,1)\equiv (0,1)$ only by having one of $x$ or $y$, wolog $x$, is even and $z$ and the other odd.

But then we have $x^2 = z^2 -y^2 = (z-y)(z+y)$  Both $z-y$ and $z+y$ as sum/difference of odd numbers are even.  But we can further claim that one is divisble by $4$ and the other isn't.

If $y = 2n + 1$ and $z=2m+1$ and $z -y = 2(m-n)$ with $m-n$ odd/even. Then $z+y= 2(m+n+1)$ with $m+n+1 = (m-n) + 2n + 1$ even/odd.  So one is $2*odd$ and the other is $2*even = 4*something$.

So $x^2 = (z-y)(z-x)$ is divisible by $8$ and $x$ is divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 1):

A generalisation of [Euclid's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) states that $a=k(m^2-n^2), b=2kmn$ and $c = k(m^2 + n^2)$ will generate any Pythagorean triple, where $m,n,k$ are positive integers, $m > n$, $m$ and $n$ are coprime, and at least one of $m,n$ is even.

This means you now have to prove that:

$$k^3(m+n)(m-n)(2mn)(m^2+n^2) \equiv 0 \pmod {60}$$

and you can do this by proving that the expression is congruent to $0 \pmod 3$, $0 \pmod 4$, and $0 \pmod 5$ as you mentioned.

Comment: So there is a closed formula that generates pythagorean triples. The question I have is, are all pythagorean triples generated by these formulas? Because if there are pythagorean triples outside them.. then I can't use them in the proof.

Comment: I have edited to provide a generalisation that can produce any Pythagorean triple.

Comment: Appreciate your effort to help, but at the same time I have to say, proving that this big equation is congruent to 0 mod 3,4,5 seems harder than proving xyz congruent to 3,4,5.

Comment: The article proves a triple is either of the form, or is a multiple of a triple of the form.

Comment: "I have to say, proving that this big equation is congruent to 0 mod 3,4,5 seems harder than proving xyz congruent to 3,4,5. "  Looks are decieving.  It's much easier.  Notice consider if $m$ is even or odd and $4$ plops right out.

Comment: Make a table where $m \equiv -2,-1,0,1,2 \pmod 5$ and $n \equiv -2,-1,0,1,2 \pmod 5$. You can immediately find that $m=0$ or $n=0$ works. Continue with the rest of conditions: $m-n$, $m+n$, and you will find that remaining numbers all have $m^2+n^2 = 0$.

Comment: Perhaps counter intuively the *more* multicands you have the *easier* it is to show it must have a specific divisor.  If you have $a^3-a$ it's not obvious  its divisible by $3$ but if you have $(a-1)a(a+1)$ it *is* obvious that *one* of them must be.  It's hard to see if $x^2+y^2=z^2$ that one of $x,y,z$ is divisible by $5$ but given the 4 terms $m+n,m-n,2mn,m^2+n^2$, if $m$ or $n\equiv 0$ or if $m\equiv n$ or $m\equiv -n$ or if one is equiv $\pm 1$ and the other equiv $\pm 2$ then one of them is divisible by $5$. The is easier BECAUSE it is bigger.  Bigger is easier.